# Load routes from api in vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to load routes in a Vue application from my API. I tried pushing data to routes variable and using addRoutes method. But no luck. I think there could be an issue with async. But why the addRoutes() not working?

Here's my code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

/**
 * Routes
*/
import item_index from '../../app/Tenant/Item/Views/Index.vue';
import contact_index from '../../app/Tenant/Contact/Views/Index.vue';
import eav_index from '../../app/Tenant/Eav/Views/create.vue';
import eav_create from '../../app/Tenant/Eav/Views/create.vue';

var routes = [
     { path: '/items', component: item_index, name: 'item_index' },
     { path: '/contact', component: eav_index , name: 'contact_index' , props: { entity_type_id: 1 }},
 ];


Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    routes
});

axios
    .get('http://c1.fmt.dev/api/eav/entity_types')
    .then(response => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var type = response.data[i];
            var route = {
                path: '/' + type.name,
                component: eav_index,
                name: type.name + '_index',
                props: {
                    entity_type_id: type.id
                },
            };

            router.addRoutes([route]);
            alert(router.options.routes);
            // alert(JSON.stringify(routes));
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
});

new Vue({
    el: '.v-app',
    data(){
      return {
        page_header: '',
        page_header_small: '',
      }
    },
    router, axios
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this improved code. Without postponing Vue instance creation, so without unnecessary delaying page interactivity:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'

import item_index from '../../app/Tenant/Item/Views/Index.vue'
import contact_index from '../../app/Tenant/Contact/Views/Index.vue'
import eav_index from '../../app/Tenant/Eav/Views/create.vue'
import eav_create from '../../app/Tenant/Eav/Views/create.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',

  routes: [{
    path: '/items',
    component: item_index,
    name: 'item_index'
  }, {
    path: '/contact',
    component: eav_index ,
    name: 'contact_index' ,
    props: {entity_type_id: 1}
  }]
})

new Vue({
  el: '.v-app',
  router,

  data () {
    return {
      page_header: '',
      page_header_small: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getDynamicRoutes (url) {
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then(this.processData)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },

    processData: ({data}) => {
      data.forEach(this.createAndAppendRoute)
    },

    createAndAppendRoute: route => {
      let newRoute = {
        path: `/${route.name}`,
        component: eav_index,
        name: `${route.name}_index`,
        props: {entity_type_id: route.id}
      }

      this.$router.addRoutes([newRoute])
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.getDynamicRoutes('http://c1.fmt.dev/api/eav/entity_types')
  }
})
```

For better code structure and readability, move router definition to separate file:

In your main file, leave just this code:

```
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'   
import router from '@/router'
import axios from 'axios'

new Vue({
  el: '.v-app',
  router,

  data () {
    return {
      page_header: '',
      page_header_small: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getDynamicRoutes (url) {
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then(this.processData)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },

    processData: ({data}) => {
      data.forEach(this.createAndAppendRoute)
    },

    createAndAppendRoute: route => {
      let newRoute = {
        path: `/${route.name}`,
        component: eav_index,
        name: `${route.name}_index`,
        props: {entity_type_id: route.id}
      }

      this.$router.addRoutes([newRoute])
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.getDynamicRoutes('http://c1.fmt.dev/api/eav/entity_types')
  }
})
```

And in same folder as main file lies, create subfolder 'router' with 'index.js' within:

```
// router/index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import item_index from '../../../app/Tenant/Item/Views/Index.vue'
import contact_index from '../../../app/Tenant/Contact/Views/Index.vue'
import eav_index from '../../../app/Tenant/Eav/Views/create.vue'
import eav_create from '../../../app/Tenant/Eav/Views/create.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',

  routes: [{
    path: '/items',
    component: item_index,
    name: 'item_index'
  }, {
    path: '/contact',
    component: eav_index ,
    name: 'contact_index' ,
    props: {entity_type_id: 1}
  }]
})
```

Comment: Do we need to import a component in main.js? I see that you refer to the component `eav_index` in `createAndAppendRoute` method in main.js.

Comment: Hm... Yes, it seems it is required to import the eav_index in main.js

Comment: Weird but this solution didn't work out for me because `this.$router` is undefined in my main.js file. Any ideas why? :( I imported router there though...

Comment: But the solution itself works: I checked this with some hardcode.

Comment: I removed arrow function in createAndAppendRoute and router became accessible but now I get an error in `addRoutes` method saying that `argument type: {path: *, component, name: string} is not assignable to parameter type RouteConfig[]`...

Comment: The previous comment was about my own mistake: I forgot to wrap a new route in square brackets. But still, if I type a path of a new route, I get 404 error that such page doesn't exist.

Comment: @OlgaB is right... this piece of code does not seem to work since lambda function context does not permit to access $router using this since this is not the whole application but only the lambda function itself. 
To avoid this, I would simply replace lambda functions with standard functions. See codepen:
https://codepen.io/dvienne/pen/dyvNgPJ

Moreover, the $router.addRoutes() method is deprecated. For this reason, I simply use $router.addRoute() passing a simple object.

Answer (score 1):

The vue instance is already initiated when you try to add the routes (same problem as in this question: [How to use addroutes method in Vue-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341016/how-to-use-addroutes-method-in-vue-router) ). You could postpone the vue initalization after the routes are loaded:

```
//imports and stuff...

axios
    .get('http://c1.fmt.dev/api/eav/entity_types')
    .then(response => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var type = response.data[i];
            var route = {
                path: '/' + type.name,
                component: eav_index,
                name: type.name + '_index',
                props: {
                    entity_type_id: type.id
                },
            };

            // extend routes array prior to router init
            routes.push(route);
        }
        // init router when all routes are known
        const router = new VueRouter({
            mode: 'history',
            linkActiveClass: 'active',
            routes
        });

        // init vuw instance when router is ready
        new Vue({
            el: '.v-app',
            data(){
              return {
                page_header: '',
                page_header_small: '',
              }
            },
            router, axios
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
});
```