# VUE js How hide routes by role in vue-router? Spa Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am writing a SPA application (laravel + vue). There was a question how to hide routes in vue-router before authorization of a user with a certain role.

Now there is such a router.js fight with routes.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../components/Calendar.vue'
import PermissionList from '../components/PermissionList.vue'
import BoardsList from '../components/BoardsList.vue'
import UsersList from '../components/UsersList.vue'
import Login from '../components/Login.vue'

const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/permission-list',
        name: 'PermissionList',
        component: PermissionList
    },
    {
        path: '/boards-list',
        name: 'BoardsList',
        component: BoardsList
    },
    {
        path: '/users-list',
        name: 'UsersList',
        component: UsersList
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/dsad',
        name: 'asd',
        component: Login
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
    linkActiveClass: "active",
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
        if (to.name == 'Login') {
            next();
        } else {
            next({
                name: 'Login'
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (to.name == 'Login') {
            next({
                name: 'Home'
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }


})

export default router
```

User data including his role and jwt token come after authorization and are stored in localstorage.

```
<template>
  <main class="form-signin text-center">
    <div>
      
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Form</h1>

      <div class="form-floating">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Login"
          v-model="login" 
        />
        <label for="floatingInput">Login</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating my-2">
        <input
          type="password"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Pass"
          v-model="password"
        />
        <label for="floatingPassword">Pass</label>
      </div>

     
      <a class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="logIn()">
        Login
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:'Login',
  data() {
    return {
      login:"",
      password:"",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    logIn() {
        this.HTTP.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            this.HTTP.post("/login",{
                email:this.login,
                password:this.password,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token',response.config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']);
                localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(response.data.user));
                this.$emit('loginUpdate');
                this.$router.push('/');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
        
    },
  },
  
};
</script>

<style>


.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}



</style>
```

if you go to the vue developer panel, all routes will be visible even before the user is authorized, how can I hide them so that unauthorized users do not see the site structure.

[image]

did you solve this problem?

Comment: The point of dev panel is that it is for development purposes. You wont have this issue when you go prod and publish the app

Comment: npm run production  should hide the dev panel (if your vue app is using mix in laravel)  otherwise compile vue in production mode.

Comment: @VenkateshA If you run a search on the build file, then you can also find all the application links there.`class:"nav-link",to:"/boards-list"},{default:(0,a.w5)((()=>[d])),_:1})]),(0,a._)("li",m,[(0,a.Wm)(b,{class:"nav-link",to:"/users-list"},{default:(0,a.w5)((()=>[p])),_:1})]),(0,a._)("li",g,[(0,a.Wm)(b,{class:"nav-link",to:"/permission-list"},{default:(0,a.w5)((()=>[h])),_:1})])])):(0,a.`

Comment: @Cameron my question is not about how to hide the panel, but how to hide all routes from unauthorized users.

Comment: oh, you are looking for Navigation guards https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards

Comment: I know about them and even slip it, but the routes are still loaded into the build before authorization.

Comment: Routes will always be loaded into the build. A SPA is client side, so the client will always be able to see the routes. If the routes are not in the build then how would an authenticated user see those routes? Javascript doesn't know about the user when the bundle is build

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed. what if we load routes as a response after authorization?

Comment: That's possible, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132533/load-routes-from-api-in-vue

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed Do you think it's right to open routes for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Just use separated js file using your mixin laravel config. One login.js, another app.js and then use each of them in separated view-laravel

Comment: i use spa architecture. A separate Vue project and a separate Laravel project. As a result, I decided to send all routes, since they are still protected through Laravel's authorization. There is an idea to send routes from Laravel to vue-router separately, but this is not necessary yet.