# Vue-router async loading url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Laravel back-end where i can manage my Urls.

In front i'm using Vuejs with vue-router

First in main.js

```
    import EstarterSettings from './plugins/EstarterSettings'
    import router from './router'
```

then i'm trying to use a plugin to load my routes in the plugin

```
    import {RestDataSourcesMixin} from '../mixins/RestDataSourcesMixin'

    export default  {
        async install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$routes = await 
                RestDataSourcesMixin.methods.requestApi(`/api/get-routes`)
        }
    };
```

Now, i want to use this routes in my vue-router

```
export default [
    {
        path: Vue.prototype.$routes.home,
        name: 'home',
        component: Views.Home,
        breadcrumb: []
    },
    {
        path: Vue.prototype.$routes.forgotten_password,
        name: 'forgottenPassword',
        component: Views.ForgottenPassword,
        meta: {
            requiresVisitor: true,
            breadcrumb: [
                { name: 'Home', link: '/' },
                { name: 'Forgotten password' }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

But cause async, routes are undefined

How can i wait for routes loading or is there a way to do this ?

Thanks a lot

**Edit**

I was able to solve my problem thanks to this link. it exactly matches what I was looking for :

[How to load all server side data on initial vue.js / vue-router load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572974/how-to-load-all-server-side-data-on-initial-vue-js-vue-router-load)

**Edit 2**

I found another way to do this.
Set my routes as global variables in the html layout before the vuejs app

```
<script>
    window.appSettings = {
        routes : {{\app\Http\Controllers\Front\System\EstarterSettingController::getRoutes()}},
        settings: {{\app\Http\Controllers\Front\System\EstarterSettingController::getSettings()}}
    }
</script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using .then() method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302614/5962802

Comment: @Ckuessner we can't put import in then()